# The shouldPauseOnSuspend for the InAppBrowser doesn't stop my YT video for being played in the background

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

Google Play rejected because it allowed playing of YouTube videos in the background, after pressing the Home button or switching to another application.

I tried using the shouldPauseOnSuspend property to prevent this, but it doesn't seem to work.
I am using the latest version of the InAppBrowser plugin for Cordova (7.0.1)
I put the

```
<preference name="shouldPauseOnSuspend" value="yes" />
```

in the config.xml

Any suggestion would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The shouldPauseOnSuspend is not set with a preference in config.xml. Instead, you need to set `shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes` within the options when calling the `open` method for the inappbrowser. See the documentation here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.

Something like this will work:

```
window.open('http://google.com','_blank', 'shouldPauseOnSuspend=yes');
```